# Django: Exception Value (2013, '2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query', None)

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-connection, django-1.7

Recently I have upgraded *Django* from version 1.6.5 to 1.7.1 and *mysql-connector-python* from 1.x to 2.0.2
After upgrading, the Exception(2013) is raised most of the time I make a query.

```
Exception Type: InterfaceError
Exception Value: (2013, '2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query', None)
```

I have added some settings about 'CONN_MAX_AGE', 'wait_timeout' but it does not help. Here are my settings:

*From command line:*

```
C:/>pip freeze
Django==1.7.1
South==1.0.1
mysql-connector-python==2.0.2
.....
C:/python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.7.1
```

*From settings.py:*

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django', 
        'NAME': 'djangodb',
        'USER': 'djangodb',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '********',   
        'PORT': '3306',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE' : 600,
    }
}
```

*MySQL settings:*

```
show variables like 'wait_timeout'; #=>28800
show variables like 'net_read_timeout'; #=>30
```

*views.py:*

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def db(request, table):
    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    if table == "table_status":
        cursor.execute("SHOW TABLE STATUS")       #No exception 4/5 times
    elif table == "processlist":
        cursor.execute("SHOW PROCESSLIST")        #No exception 4/5 times
    elif table == "status":
        cursor.execute("SHOW STATUS")             #No exception 4/5 times
    elif table == "variables":
        cursor.execute("SHOW VARIABLES")          #Exception is raised 49/50 times

    if(cursor):    
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        description = cursor.description
        cursor.close()
        return render_to_response("myadmin/table.html", {"title": table, "headers":description,"data":data})
    else:
        return render_to_response("ajax/error404.html")
```

Please help me fix the problem.

Comment: I've never seen that database ENGINE before. In my fresh Django 1.7 install, it shows 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'

Comment: Database Engine is configured following [this tutorial](http://bunwich.blogspot.com/2014/02/finally-mysql-connector-that-works-with.html) and [this tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I did some digging around, and it looks like this is a [known issue with Django 1.7 and version 2.0.2 of mysql-connector-python.](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74696)

The bug is marked as "resolved" in version 2.0.3, but is not released yet.

EDIT: Downgrading to version 1.2.3 has been reported as a temporary solution by OP:

```
pip install -U --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python==1.2.3
```

Comment: The mysql-connector-python has caused the problem indeed. Version 2.0.3 not yet released so I downgraded the mysql-connection-python to version 1.2.3. It fixed the problem. Thank you very much.

`pip install -U --allow-external mysql-connector-python  mysql-connector-python==1.2.3`