# Django error connecting to MySQL - handshake

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am getting an error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading inital communication packet', system error: 0")

I can connect to the database fine through python outside of django using pyodbc, but when I try to connect through django, it errors out.

I originally didn't have the max timeout setting. I added this to see if it helped.

My database is an ip connection, 192.168.2.10, port 49170.

With pyodbc, I can connect with:

```
import pyodbc

server = '192.168.2.10\EDSQL'
database = 'spamfilter' # 'acme'
username = 'sa'
password = 'xxxxx'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.2.10,49170;DATABASE=spamfilter;UID=sa;PWD=3dd!3Sn!p3s')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

My django settings.py are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'spamfilter',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxx',
        'HOST': '192.168.2.10',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '49170',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,
    }
}
```

The error occurs when performing the initial python manage.py migrate

Comment: This could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309187/django-exception-value-2013-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-que
However, it seems like it's a bug from a very old version